# Transfer Word 2007 AutoCorrect entries from one machine to another

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2007, autocorrect

I have two computers that both have Office 2007 installed on them (an old machine, and a replacement).

How would I go about exporting the AutoCorrect entries on one machine and then importing them to another?

Comment: What version of Windows are they on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I haven't tried this (sorry), but I am pretty sure it will work.*

Copy the appropriate `.acl` file, from the existing machine, onto the replacement machine.

Found here (on Windows Vista): **C:\Users\USERNAME\Application Data\Microsoft\Office\**
or here (on Windows XP): **C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\Application Data\Microsoft\Office\**

The file you're looking for will have a name like *MSO1234.acl*. The 4 numbers refer to the language/locale code. Yours will most probably be either **MSO2057.acl** (for UK) or **MSO1033.acl** (for USA). Also, it's likely to be the one with the largest file size.

I recommend making sure all instances of Microsoft Office programs are closed before you make this change.

This will most likely replace the existing AutoCorrect entries saved on the second machine.